# C# Active Directory Invoke "ChangePassword" cannot contact domain

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, change-password, account-management

I have the following code as part of a web application for my Active Directory users to be able to update their passwords (for active directory and gmail at the same time).  I am using C# with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.

This code worked until *yesterday*

```
try
{
    State.log.WriteLine("Connecting LDAP.");
    string ldapPath = "LDAP://192.168.76.3";
    DirectoryEntry directionEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, domainName + "\\" + userName, currentPassword);
    if (directionEntry != null)
    {
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(directionEntry);
        State.log.WriteLine("LDAP Connected, searching directory for SAMAccountName");
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        if (result != null)
        {
            State.log.WriteLine("Getting User Entry.");
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
            if (userEntry != null)
            {
                State.log.WriteLine("Setting Password");
                if (force)
                {
                    userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new[] { newPassword });
                }
                else
                {
                    userEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { currentPassword, newPassword });
                }
                userEntry.CommitChanges();
                State.log.WriteLine("Changes Committed to ActiveDirectory.");
            }
            else
            {
                State.log.WriteLine("Could not get user Entry...");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            State.log.WriteLine("Search returned no results.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        State.log.WriteLine("Could not connect to LDAP with given username and passwd");
    }
}
```

Since yesterday, this code makes it to the line:

```
userEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { currentPassword, newPassword });
```

and then throws the following exception:

> [8:37:00 AM] :  Password Requirements Met.
>
> [8:37:00 AM] :  Connecting LDAP.
>
> [8:37:00 AM] :  LDAP Connected, searching directory for SAMAccountName
>
> [8:37:01 AM] :  Getting User Entry.
>
> [8:37:01 AM] :  Setting Password
>
> [8:37:01 AM] :  Failed to reset Windows Password for jason.
>
> ---
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> ---
>
> The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request. Please try again later. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704F1)

The "force" option using "SetPassword" still works just fine, but the "ChangePassword" method which can be invoked by non-administrator users does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier this month Microsoft [released a security patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177108), resolving some vulnerabilities in the area of password change. Specifically, the update blocked fallback to NTLM authentication after a failed Kerberos authentication when changing a password.

You might want to read more about the update [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS16-101).

Answer (score 1):

Change userPrincipal.ChangePassword("Old pass", "New Pass"); to `userPrincipal.SetPassword(model.NewPassword);`

Comment: A user conetext without administrative rights cannot invoke SetPassword.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around and forgot to post it.  What I did was use the code above to authenticate the user and then just call my "ForceChangePassword" method:

```
public static void ForceChangeADPassword(String username, String newPassword)
{
    String DN = "";
    try
    {
        DN = GetObjectDistinguishedName(objectClass.user, returnType.distinguishedName, username, DOMAIN_CONTROLLER_IP);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new PasswordException(String.Format("Could not find AD User {0}", username), e);
    }

    if(DN.Equals(""))
        throw new PasswordException(String.Format("Could not find AD User {0}", username));

    DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(DN.Replace("LDAP://", LdapRootPath), "accounts", AcctPwd);
    userEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { newPassword });
    userEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0;

    userEntry.CommitChanges();
    userEntry.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has updated this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177108 . Here they have given us problems created by the original "fixes" as well as some tips for working with Kerberos and self-service password reset.

As of October 11, 2016 Microsoft re-released the patches associated with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms16-101.aspx to resolve issues caused by the original updates (which you can read in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3177108 including the fact that you could no longer change passwords on local accounts).